# Symbols not supported using varchar in SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I was assigned to do a task.... I have a page with some text boxes and a save button, when I enter values to the textboxes and click save button data will be saved to the databases.

In SQL Server the datatype of all columns is `varchar`. In some cases the data will not be saved properly, and click save button at that time no error will be displayed, but all the values will be disappeared.

I think some symbols are not supported using `varchar`. I am not sure what was the problem, plz help me

Comment: Please share some sample inputs, expected & actual output in support of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

`varchar` in SQL Server only supports **non-Unicode** characters, so if you have e.g. Cyrillic, Hebrew, Arabic, Chinese or other "non-Latin" characters, you'll lose some of them.

See the official [MSDN documentation on char and varchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx):

> *`varchar [ ( n | max ) ]`*
>
> *Variable-length, **non-Unicode** string data.*

Use `nvarchar(n)` as your datatype instead - this will store **Unicode** text and preserve all those special characters

Comment: using varchar i have no problem with using uncode characters.any other idea about my issue

Comment: `varchar` is **NOT** Unicode capable!

Comment: but i am using such symbols,it will be saved to the database.

Comment: @Monica: why don't you just **try** using `nvarchar` and see if that solves your problem. Trust me: `varchar` is ***NOT*** Unicode capable!

Comment: Lead a horse to water...